# How to use environment variable from Azure DevOps agent in container options?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I want to parametrize container options in Azure Pipelines with environment variables defined in a self-hosted Azure DevOps agent.

The variable is correctly visible in the agent's capabilities in "agent pools" settings.
However, I cannot access it in container options - every time there is an error that such variable is undefined or it does not evaluate.

From docs, I know that only template expressions can be used in container options.
I have tried such approaches:

1. Access environment variable directly via template expression.

```yaml
- job:
  container:
    image: $(DOCKER_IMAGE)
    options: --device=${{ TEST }}
```

CI failed with the error: `Unrecognized value: 'TEST'`.

2. Use a job variable to allow template expression to refer to something valid.

```yaml
 - job:
   variables:
   - name: TEST2 # <---------
     value: ${{ TEST }}
   container:
     image: $(DOCKER_IMAGE)
     options: --device=${{ variables.TEST2 }}
```

CI failed with errors: `Unrecognized value: 'TEST'`.

3. Use a runtime expression to get capability value.

```yaml
 - job:
   variables:
   - name: TEST2
     value: $(TEST) # <---------
   container:
     image: $(DOCKER_IMAGE)
     options: --device=${{ variables.TEST2 }}
```

Initialize containers job failed with Docker error: `docker: $(TEST) is not an absolute path.`.

4. Use bash variable expression to get capability value.

```yaml
 - job:
   variables:
   - name: TEST2
     value: ${TEST} # <---------
   container:
     image: $(DOCKER_IMAGE)
     options: --device=${{ variables.TEST2 }}
```

Initialize containers job failed with Docker error: `docker: ${TEST} is not an absolute path.`.

Is it even possible to be done?

Comment: does the environmental variable show up if you do a simple `echo` in a `bash` task?

Comment: In the job before the one that is launched in container - yes.

Comment: Does the answer from @jessehouwing help solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An environment variable isn't the same thing as an Azure Pipelines variable. Though they are related.

### Pipeline variables

These are defined in

- The pipeline's variables section
- in YAML
- in a linked variable group
- by a step in the pipeline

[These variables are available during YAML pipeline expansion and/or runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax) and can be referenced using `$(VARIABLE_NAME)` or `${{ variables['VARIABLE_NAME] }}` / `${{ variables.VARIABLE_NAME }}` or `$[ variables['VARIABLE_NAME'] ]` / `$[ variables.VARIABLE_NAME ]`.

These variables are also available inside the steps of a pipeline through the environment where they can be accessed using:

```
# bash
$VARIABLE_NAME

# pwsh
$env:VARIABLE_NAME

# cmd
%VARIABLE_NAME%
```

(Note: The name is capitalized and certain characters are replaced by `_`).

### Environment variables

As you saw above, pipeline variables are made available as environment variables together with all the environment variables of that are registered on the System, Agent and User that runs the Azure Pipeline.

These environment variables are available as capabilities of an agent (to target jobs to specific agents) and can be referenced by tasks. HOWEVER, these variables can usually only be referenced from inside the task itself, but can't be passed to the input of a task, nor can they be used in conditions.

For example: a task may accept a snippet of script to execute, like the PowerShell task:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs: 
      script: | 
        write-host $env:VARIABLE_NAME
```

In this case the variable's value is not expanded until the PowerShell host actually interprets the snippet. PowerShell will then search the environment for the variable with that name and substitute it.

### Remark

To make matters worse, the PowerShell task above could receive a mixture of variable references in its script block:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs: 
      script: |
        write-host $VARIABLE_NAME                     #1
        write-host $(VARIABLE_NAME)                   #2
        write-host $[ variables.VARIABLE_NAME ]       #3
        write-host ${{ variables.VARIABLE_NAME }}     #4
        write-host $env:VARIABLE_NAME                 #5
```

Each of these behaves differently:

1. This is an actual PowerShell variable. If it was assigned a value in the script before, it will print that value It's not related to any environment variable or azure pipelines variable. PowerShell will see: `$VARIABLE_NAME`.
2. This is an Azure Pipelines variable that is inlined in the script just before the script is passed to PowerShell. If a variable with this name exists, the contents will be merged with the script. PowerShell will not know the value came from Azure Pipelines. Since it's inlined at runtime, the value can be can be changed a previous step. PowerShell will see: `contents of the variable`.
3. This is also a Azure Pipelines variable that is inlined in the script when the job is prepared. Inlining happens earlier, but it will take into account values from previous jobs etc. PowerShell will see: `contents of the variable`.
4. This is also an Azure Pipelines variable that is inlined when the YAML is parsed. Any variable that is set or changed during runtime is completely ignored. This will only take values into account that are defined on the variables tab, variable groups or hardcoded in the YAML. PowerShell will see: `contents of the variable`.
5. This references an environment variable. Like the `$VARIABLE_NAME` above it's not substituted or inlined by Azure Pipelines, but the value is retrieved by the powershell host that executes the task. If there happens to be an Azure Pipelines variable with the same name, then it will take the value of that Azure Pipelines variable, but it can also refer to a User, Agent, or System environment variable. PowerShell will see: `$env:VARIABLE_NAME`.

### A trick

[If you want to raise an environment variable to a runtime usable Azure Pipelines variable, you can use the magic logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    inputs: 
      script: |
        write-host echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VARIABLE_NAME;]$env:VARIABLE_NAME"
```

This will register an Azure Pipelines variable for the duration of the job that will be accessible using the runtime variable syntax `$(VARIABLE_NAME)` or `$[ variables.VARIABLE_NAME]`.

You can't refer to these variables using `${{ ... }}` as the value of the variable won't be available at YAML compile time.

[If you want the variable to be available across jobs, you can set an output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs). This trick may work in your case. In a special job used to setup the output variables. Then reference these output variables in the subsequent job that contains the logic you already have. Just make sure both jobs use the same agent.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VARIABLE_NAME;isoutput=true]$env:VARIABLE_NAME"
    name: passOutput
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.myOutputVar'] ]  
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo $(myVarFromJobA)
```

Comment: Ok, so basically options parametrization depending on particular agent config is impossible.

Comment: There's tricks...  You could use a script to raise the environment variable to a pipeline variable at runtime. See above.